# Не работает функция изменения цены товара JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не работает функция `SelectPieces`. Функция должна менять в классе `price` цену, относительно единицы измерения (штуки, тонны, комплекты). Далее функция `tocart должна добавлять товар, относительно выбранной единицы измерения.

Кроме этого на странице отображаются похожие товары, код не стал прикреплять. Идея в том, что `id` товаров пересекаются в модулях "похожие товары" и "сопутствующие", поэтому нужна была функция без использования `id`. В силу того, что нету проблем с расчетом самой цены, все не стал выкладывать. Для лучшего понимания, вот пример страницы отображения 
http://t.itex.ru/uralmet_new/katalog/transportnyiy_metaloprokat/relsyi/relsyi_promyishlennyie_rp50_rp65/rp65_t_dt

Вот код:

```js
function tocart(url, id, modelName, count, unit, reload) {
    if (count.length == 0 || count == 0) {
        count = 1;
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        data: {"modelName": modelName, "modelPk": id, "count": count, "unit": unit},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.cartMessage != false) {
                $('.cart-info p span').html(data.count);
                $('#send').arcticmodal();
                //$('#unitsProd' + id).prop( true);
            }
            if (reload == true) {
                document.location.reload();
            }
        }


    });
}
//Нужна аналогичная функция tocart без привязки к id 

$.fn.selectPieces = function(){
    var unit = $(this.find('#unitsProd').val());
    $(this.find('.priceFor')).hide();
    if (unit ==2) {
        $(this.find('.priceFor').show());
    }
    else if (unit == 0) {
        $(this.find('#priceP').show());
    } else {
        $(this.find('#priceT').show());
    }

};

function selectPieces(id) {
    var unit = $('#unitsProd' + id).val();
    $('.priceFor' + id).hide();
    if (unit ==2) {
        $('#priceK' + id).show();
    }
        else if (unit == 0) {
            $('#priceP' + id).show();
        } else {
            $('#priceT' + id).show();
        }

}

function cangeCountCart(id, count, url, item_id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'action.changeCount',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        data: {"shopItemId": id, "mes": '', "newCount": count},
        success: function (data) {
            var priceray2 = JSON.parse(data.priceray2);
            var cray = JSON.parse(data.cray);
            for (key in priceray2) {
                if (priceray2[key] == 0) {
                    $('#sum' + key + ' span').html('договорная');
                } else {
                    $('#sum' + key + ' span').html('от ' + priceray2[key]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

function changeUnit(id, prodId) {
    var unit = $('#unitsProd' + id).val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'action.changeUnit',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        data: {"id": id, "unit": unit, "prodId": prodId},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#sum' + id + ' span').html(data.sum);
            $('#price' + id).html(data.price);
        }
    });
}

function deletItemCart(modelName, modelPk, count, countIt) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'action.dellToCart',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        data: {"modelName": modelName, "modelPk": modelPk, "count": count},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.bigcount == 0) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
            $('.thisIsTable').html(data.vewHtml);
            $('.cart-info p span').html(data.bigcount);
        }
    });
}

function countPlus(id, count, url) {
    var newCount = parseInt(count) + 1;
    cangeCountCart(id, newCount, url);
}
function countMinus(id, count, url) {
    var newCount = parseInt(count) - 1;
    cangeCountCart(id, newCount, url);
}


function renderGift(id) {
    $('.catalog-other-menu ul li').removeClass('on');
    $('#' + id).addClass('on');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$url = Yii::app()->createUrl('/action.addToCart');
if (!empty($order)) {
    $needle = $model->id;
    $result = array_filter($order->products, function ($mass) use ($needle) {
        return ($mass['model_pk'] == $needle);
    });
    if (!empty($result)) {
        $result = array_values($result);
        $unit = $result['0']['unit'];
    }
}

?>
<h1 class="title"><?php echo $this->getPageH1(); ?></h1>
<div class="catalog-big">
    <div class="cat-big row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 img-cat-big">
            <?php echo CHtml::image(ImageCache::image($model->image, array('280', '280', 'crop', 'fill')), $model->name); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 left-cat-big">
            <?php echo $model->productInfo->dopInfo; ?>
            <div class="left-cat-big__add-to-cart">
         <?php if (!isset($unit)) {$unit = 1; $reset = 1;} ?>
                <div class="price-big priceFor<?= $model->id; ?>" id="priceP<?= $model->id; ?>" <?php if ($unit != 0) echo 'style="display: none"'; ?>>
                    <p><strong>Цена: </strong><span><?= $model->getPrice(0,true); ?></span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="price-big priceFor<?= $model->id; ?>" id="priceT<?= $model->id; ?>" <?php if ($unit != 1) echo 'style="display: none"'; ?>>
                    <p><strong>Цена: </strong><span><?= $model->getPrice(1,true); ?></span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="price-big priceFor<?= $model->id; ?>" id="priceK<?= $model->id; ?>" <?php if ($unit != 2) echo 'style="display: none"'; ?>>
                    <p><strong>Цена: </strong><span><?= $model->getPrice(2,true); ?></span></p>
                </div>
            <?php if (isset($reset))   ?>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" value="1" id="count<?= $model->id; ?>">
                    <select id="unitsProd<?= $model->id; ?>" <?php if (isset($unit)) /* echo 'disabled';*/ ?>
                            onchange="selectPieces(<?= $model->id; ?>)">
                  <?php if (!isset($unit)) $unit = 1; ?>
                        <option <?php if ($unit == 0) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="0">шт</option>
                        <option <?php if ($unit == 1) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="1">тн</option>
                        <option <?php if ($unit == 2) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="2">компл</option> <!--Добавлен комплект-->
                    </select>
                </form>

                <div class="car-cat-big" id="count">
                    <?php //onclick="$('#send').arcticmodal()"?>
                    <a class="push-cell" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="tocart('<?= $model->url; ?>', '<?= $model->id; ?>','<?= $model->model ?>',$('#count<?= $model->id; ?>').val(),$('#unitsProd<?= $model->id; ?>').val());return false;">
                        Отправить запрос
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--var_dump ($model);-->
<?php
//var_dump ($model->url);
//var_dump ($model->id);
//var_dump ($item->model);
echo $model->content; unset($unit); ?>

<?php
If ($same_items) {
    ?>
    <div class="relation">
        <h2 class="title">Сопутствующие товары</h2>
        <div class="relation-slider">
            <?
            foreach ($same_items as $value) :
                var_dump ($value->url);
            //var_dump($value->getPrice());
            //echo __DIR__;
            ?>
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="<?= $value->url; ?>" class="relation__img"><img src="<?= $value->image; ?>"
                                                                                        alt="<?= $value->url;  ?>"></a>
                <div class="relation__name">
                    <a href="<?= $value->url; ?>"><?= $value->name; ?></a></div>
                <div class="relation__form">
                    <div class="left-cat-big__add-to-cart">
                        <form class="a-form-<?= $value->id ?>">
                            <input type="text" value="1" class="productCount">
                            <select class="priceType" id="unitsProdA<?= $value->id; ?>" <!--id="count--><?/*= $value->id; */?>" <?php
                            ?>
                                    onchange="$(this).selectPieces(<?= $value->id; ?>)"><?php if (!isset($unit)) $unit = 1; ?>
                                <?php if (!isset($unit)) $unit = 1; ?>
                                <option <?php if ($unit == 0) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="0">шт</option>
                                <option <?php if ($unit == 1) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="1">тн</option>
                                <option <?php if ($unit == 2) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="2">компл</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                        <div class="relation__price">
                            <div class="price"><?php if ($unit = 0) {
                                    echo $value->getPrice(0) . " руб";
                                } elseif ($unit = 1) {
                                    echo $value->getPrice(1) . " руб";
                                } elseif ($unit = 2) {
                                    echo $value->getPrice(2) . " руб";
                                }//$value->getPrice(2)
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="to-cart">
                                <button type="button" role="button"  onClick="tocart('<?=$url; ?>', '<?=$value->id; ?>','<?=$value->model; ?>'
                                    ,$('.a-form-<?= $value->id ?>').find('.productCount').val(),$('a-form-<?= $value->id ?>').find('.priceType').val());return
                                false;"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <? endforeach; unset($value); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
<h2 class="title">Другие товары в этом разделе</h2>
<?php if (!empty($otherCats)): ?>
    <div class="catalog row">
    <?php foreach ($otherCats as $item):
        unset($unit);
        if (!empty($order)) {
            $needle = $item->id;
            $result = array_filter($order->products, function ($mass) use ($needle) {
                return ($mass['model_pk'] == $needle);
            });
            if (!empty($result)) {
                $result = array_values($result);
                $unit = $result['0']['unit'];
            }
        } ?>
        <div class="cat col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
            <div class="left-cat">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 product-item__list-item-side">
                  <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image(ImageCache::image($item->image, array('150', '150', 'crop', 'fill')), $item->name), $item->url); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 product-item__list-item-side product-item__list-item-text">
                    <?php echo CHtml::link($item->name, $item->url); ?>
                    <div class="product-item__list-item-cart">
                      <form>
                          <input type="text" value="1" id="count<?= $item->id; ?>">
                          <select id="unitsProd<?= $item->id; ?>" <?php if (isset($unit)) echo 'disabled'; ?>
                                  onchange="selectPieces(<?= $item->id; ?>)">
                          <?php $unit = 1; ?>
                              <option <?php if ($unit == 0) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="0">шт</option>
                              <option <?php if ($unit == 1) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="1">тн</option>
                              <option <?php if ($unit == 2) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="2">компл</option>
                          </select>
                      </form>
                      <div class="price priceFor<?= $item->id; ?>"
                           id="priceP<?= $item->id; ?>" <?php if ($unit == 1) echo 'style="display: none"'; ?>>
                          <p><?= $item->getPrice(0,true); ?></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="price priceFor<?= $item->id; ?>"
                           id="priceT<?= $item->id; ?>" <?php if ($unit != 1) echo 'style="display: none"'; ?>>
                          <p><?= $item->getPrice(1,true); ?></p>
                      </div>
                        <div class="price priceFor<?= $item->id; ?>"
                             id="priceK<?= $item->id; ?>" <?php if ($unit != 2) echo 'style="display: none"'; ?>>
                            <p><?= $item->getPrice(2,true); ?></p>
                        </div>
                 <?php unset($unit); ?>
                      <div class="car-cat">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);"
                             onClick="tocart('<?= $url; ?>', '<?= $item->id; ?>','<?= $item->model; ?>',$('#count<?= $item->id; ?>').val(),$('#unitsProd<?= $item->id; ?>').val());return false;">
                          </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```
function tocart(url, id, modelName, count, unit, reload) {
if (count.length == 0 || count == 0) {
    count = 1;
}
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    data: {"modelName": modelName, "modelPk": id, "count": count, "unit": unit},
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.cartMessage != false) {
            $('.cart-info p span').html(data.count);
            $('#send').arcticmodal();
            //$('#unitsProd' + id).prop( true);
        }
        if (reload == true) {
            document.location.reload();
        }
    }


});
}
$.fn.selectPieces = function(){
var unit = $(this.find('#unitsProd').val());
$(this.find('.priceFor')).hide();
if (unit ==2) {
    $(this.find('.priceFor').show());
}
else if (unit == 0) {
    $(this.find('#priceP').show());
} else {
    $(this.find('#priceT').show());
}

};

  function selectPieces(id) {
  var unit = $('#unitsProd' + id).val();
  $('.priceFor' + id).hide();
  if (unit ==2) {
    $('#priceK' + id).show();
}
    else if (unit == 0) {
        $('#priceP' + id).show();
    } else {
        $('#priceT' + id).show();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Без форматирования это ей богу како-то ад. Ну и самое веселое что если у тебя ошибка в функции js причем тут метка php, ну и самый ахтунг, у тебя две функции одна в видимости window вторая расширяет jquery в одной ты используешь входящий id в другой нет, но в коде ты параметр передаешь, может ты ожидаешь что сработает глобальная selectPrices

Comment: + `$(this.find('#priceP').show());` явно что-то с синтаксисом не то